# Shift images in tensorflow (with periodic boundary)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I want to translate an image in Tensorflow and fill zeros with those elements cropped when using `tf.contrib.image.transform`. It means pictures have a periodic boundary condition. Suppose I have an image:

```
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
9  10 11 12
```

And I want to shift the image by dx = -1 (to left), dy = -1 (upward). The result should look like

```
6  7  8  5
10 11 12 9
2  3  4  1
```

Does any one have an efficient way to do this? (This operation appears a lot in the net).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`tf.manip.roll`](http://devdocs.io/tensorflow~python/tf/manip/roll)

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, ],
              [5, 6, 7, 8, ],
              [9, 10, 11, 12]]).astype(np.float32)


data_in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

data = tf.manip.roll(data_in, -1, 1)
data = tf.manip.roll(data, -1, 2)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(data, {data_in: a[None, :, :, None]}))
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I want.